# Is there a way to cope with undefined reference error for template functions without implementing them in header?

Tags: c++, templates, undefined-reference

I hope the problem is clear. Is there an alternative way not to get undefined reference error without implementing template functions in header files? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Marshall Cline's C++-FAQ already deals with this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html#faq-35.14).

One way is to use **export** but I don't really recommend using it because not all compilers support it really!

In fact C++0x Committee has voted out **export** out of the next C++ Standard.

Answer (score 3):

If you know in advance which all instantiations you will need, you can instantiate them manually.